# How to save failed pie crust dough (warm butter)?

Tags: butter, pie, crust

OK, I've accidentally used warm butter in a common pie crust recipe (250 g flour + 205 g butter + salt + cold water). The dough formed before I could even add some water at it does not look like the dough you could form a normal pie crust from - it is barely rollable at all. What can I do to turn it into a more or less usable pie crust or anything else usable at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a recipe I saw a while ago that uses butter that's thoroughly incorporated into the flour instead of the usual cold chunks.  I think it creates a butter/flour paste, then cuts fresh flour into it just prior to adding the water (the idea being that instead of layers of tricky-to-work-with pure butter separating layers of water-dough, you would have more workable layers of butter-flour paste separating layers of water-dough).

In that case, assuming your mention of 'the dough coming together before you added water', means you have mostly butter and flour in the bowl at this point, you might add more butter to it so the ratios work out, and treat your whole first batch like that butter/flour paste.  You will need to cut fresh flour into it, since the paste is only supposed to contain 2/3 of the recipe's flour and all the butter, so it might take some math to figure out how to make what you already have fit into the ratios neatly.  Then add the water and gently bring it together into a dough, refrigerate for a couple hours, and roll as normal.

This might still work even if you've added water, maybe making a smaller portion of the butter/flour paste to cut into the dough, and adding a balancing amount of flour and water afterwards - you should still get some of the texture benefits, although not as much as if the whole batch were done the same way.

You will end up with more dough in either case, but you can either chill the leftover dough, or pre-divide and store the leftover portion of the butter-flour mix, and it should store pretty well (both flour and butter store well in the fridge).

(I have found the original recipe, it can be found [here](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/07/easy-pie-dough-recipe.html), and the sciency-rationale over [here](http://www.seriouseats.com/2015/03/science-of-pie-7-myths-that-need-to-go-away.html), at seriouseats.com)

Comment: In the end, I have used the half of the failed dough as a pie crust and it turned not bad - short-bread cookie-like but, nevertheless, doing its job (holding the filling and being yummy). I've put the other half into the freezer and then used it to add to flour with more properly cold butter, making a pair of perfect flaky crusts. So, thanks for a nice solution!